# Separation of variables (pde): Why does the ansatz give this right-hand side?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Suppose $w(x,t)=X(t)T(t)$, i.e. we can express $w$ as a product of a function that only depends on $x$ and another that only depends on $t$.

Moreover, let $D=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & d\end{pmatrix}$ and consider
$$
w_t=D\Delta w.~~~(*)
$$

If we put $w(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$ into $(*)$, we get $X(x)T'(t)$ on the left hand side. Ok, that's clear.

> > On the right-hand side, it is said, we get $X''(x)T(t)$.

I do not see the right hand side at all!

If we plug the ansatz $w(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$ into $(*)$ why should we get
$$
D\Delta w=D\Delta (X(x)T(t))=X''(x)T(t)?
$$

This is claimed [here, on page 19 of the pdf-document](http://math.gmu.edu/~sander/studentpapers/robertallenthesis0803.pdf).

Am I missing something?

Comment: Apply the definition of the Laplacian.

Comment: I did, but what I get is that $D\Delta (X(x)T(t))=D(X''(x)T(t)+T''(t)X(x))$.

Comment: What is the meaning of $'$ ?

Comment: For the X(x), it is $d/dx$ and for the T it is $d/dt$. Maybe thats the origin of my fault.

Comment: Yes, that's the origin of your troubles.

Comment: Could you please tell me how it is done correctly? I am a bit confused now.

Comment: Write down the definition of the Laplacian.

Comment: $\Delta (X(x)T(t))=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}(X(x)T(t)) + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}(X(x)T(t))$

Comment: Nope, this is not the definition of the Laplacian (unless $t$ denotes a coordinate, which is highly unlikely).

Comment: $\Delta (X(x)T(t))=\nabla^2 (X(x)T(t))$. But how to work with this?!

Comment: Write down the definition of operator Nabla.

Comment: $\nabla(X(x)T(t))=((X(x)T(t))_x, (X(x)T(t))_t))$

Comment: Nope, this is not the definition of the Nabla operator.

Comment: Sorry, I do not come along with your step by step advices.

Comment: @Rhjg Usually, the Laplace-operator is only applied on the variable $x$, So what you get is that $\Delta_x(X(x)T(t))=X''(x)T(t)$. But do not know what happens with the matrix $D$.

Comment: It looks like you are solving a Heat equation in $1$ spatial dimension. If this is the case then $\Delta \equiv \nabla^2 = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}$.

Comment: Yes, but I do not understand what happens with the matrix $D$. I guess it is one spatial dimension (that is the x), but D is a matrix.. so there seem to be 2 equations?

Comment: Note that $w$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $D\Delta w \equiv D \pmatrix{\Delta w_1\\ \Delta w_2}= D \pmatrix{\frac{\partial^2 w_1}{\partial x^2}\\\frac{\partial^2 w_2}{\partial x^2}}$ where $w_1,w_2$ are the components of $w$

Comment: I then get $\begin{pmatrix}X''(x)T(t)\\d X(x)T''(t)\end{pmatrix}$ as right hand side. Hence, the separation ansatz gives me $X(t)T'(t)=\begin{pmatrix}X''(x)T(t)\\d X(x)T''(t)\end{pmatrix}$. But does this make sense? And how can I now bring the variables on one side each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you are solving for is a *vector* ${\bf w}  = \pmatrix{u\\v}$ and not a scalar. For your purposes it might be better to work directly with the components to avoid any confusion about this issue.

A scalar differential operator acting on a vector means that it acts on all the components of that vector:

$$\frac{\partial {\bf w}}{\partial t} \equiv \pmatrix{\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\\ \frac{\partial v}{\partial t}},~~~~~~~\Delta {\bf w} \equiv \pmatrix{\Delta u\\ \Delta v}$$

You are solving a Heat equation in only $1$ spatial dimension for which the Laplacian is simply

$$\Delta \equiv \nabla^2  = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}$$

Using this the equation you are solving can be written out in component form as

$$\frac{\partial {\bf w} }{\partial t} = D\Delta {\bf w} \implies \pmatrix{\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\\\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}} = \pmatrix{1 & 0\\0 & d}\pmatrix{\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}\\\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x^2}} = \pmatrix{\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}\\d\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x^2}}$$

This gives you *two* equations

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2},~~~~~~~~\frac{\partial v}{\partial t} = d\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x^2}$$

which you can apply separation of variables on to solve. In practice you only need to solve one as the second equation is just the first with a rescaled time coordinate $t\to d\cdot t$.

When you apply separation of variables $u = X(x) T(t)$ note that $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ *only* acts on $T$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ *only* acts on $X$ so for example

$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} = \frac{\partial^2 X(x)}{\partial x^2}T(t)$$

You seem to use the same short-hand symbol $'$ for derivatives wrt $x$ and $t$. This is not a good habit and will easily lead to mistakes. Either use a different notation like $\frac{\partial T}{\partial t} = \dot{T}$ and  $\frac{\partial X}{\partial x} = X'$ or stick with $\frac{\partial T}{\partial t},\frac{\partial X}{\partial x}$.

Comment: For $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\Delta u$, I get the solution $u(x,t)=\sum_k c_k \exp(-k^2t)\cos((kx)/a),~k=\pi n$, if we consider $\Omega=(0,a), a>0$. Then, for $v(x,t)$, we have the same solution, but only go faster or slower (depending on the value of $d$) through it since $dt$ instead of $t$. Right?

Comment: Btw: Maybe you could help me with this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1583828/how-to-make-the-separation-of-variables-eigenfunction-expansion-here too. It seems to be very connected.